# Unclaimed Status in PayPal

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am new to PayPal Express checkout development.

My developer account is UK based, when i am trying to capture an order in EUR or USD currency type my order status in the sandbox account is going to an unclaimed status. While the orders in GBP is working fine.

I have gone through the scenarios for which the PP order status goes to unclaimed status,

Is there any configuration to change my developer account to accept all currency modes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your PayPal account.
Click Profile at the top of the page.
Click My selling tools.
Click Update in the Block payments section.

Choose `No` for `Block payments sent to you in a currency you don't hold.`
Update your settings and click Save.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply.. I logged into the sandbox acct through which i paid the amt but i couldnt able to find any options like u have mentioned. Are u mentioning abt the developer paypal acct ?

Comment: you need to login o seller account

Comment: You mean the account which we give in the API credentials of our application like username ,pass , signature etc.. Since i have four account tagged to my developer acct i couldnt able to find which is the seller acct..